# How to fetch best OCR text results from photo library in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, vision

I am using this Link for developing OCR text recognition.

https://github.com/khurram18/SceneTextRecognitioniOS

https://devcrew.io/2017/09/11/scene-text-recognition-ios-11/

It gives best results when camera open. but I want to recognise text from photo library also. but it is not giving best results. could you please any one guide me to do this task. I have attached my Source code also:

```
func textAnalyze() {

    let textDetectionRequest = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: {(request, error) in

        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNTextObservation]
            else { fatalError("unexpected result type from VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest") }

        self.addShapesToText(forObservations: observations)
    })

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: self.imgView.image!.cgImage!, options: [:])

    guard let _ = try? handler.perform([textDetectionRequest]) else {
        return print("Could not perform text Detection Request!")
    }

}

func addShapesToText(forObservations observations: [VNTextObservation]) {

    if let layers = self.imgView.layer.sublayers {
        for layer in layers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }

    let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imgView.image!.size, insideRect: imgView.bounds)

    let layers: [CAShapeLayer] = observations.map { observation in

        let w = observation.boundingBox.size.width * imageRect.width
        let h = observation.boundingBox.size.height * imageRect.height
        let x = observation.boundingBox.origin.x * imageRect.width + imageRect.origin.x
        let y = imageRect.maxY - (observation.boundingBox.origin.y * imageRect.height) - h

        print("----")
        print("W: ", w)
        print("H: ", h)
        print("X: ", x)
        print("Y: ", y)

        let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: self.imgView.image!.cgImage!)

        tesseract?.image = uiImage
        tesseract?.recognize()
        var text = tesseract?.recognizedText

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            text = text!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.newlines) + "\n"

            print("text\(String(describing: text))")

            self.textViewSample.text += text!

        }

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: x , y: y, width: w, height: h)
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.cornerRadius = 3
        return layer
    }

    for layer in layers {
        self.imgView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
         ///self.textRecognition()

    }
}
```

Comment: Vision now does OCR out of the box, not just detecting characters. You might want to consider using Apple's "factory" framework instead of Tesseract.

Comment: @Adrian: Could you please share any links to do this task using factory

Comment: Check WWDC videos from 2019. Also, I posted an answer to my own question. If you click my profile under my questions you’ll see it.